# XSLT: Add Attribute to parent based on child attribute value containing a specific string

Tags: xslt, wix, wix3.5

I am using an xslt transform on the harvested files file in a WIX installation. I am trying to mark all files in certain directories as permanent. In order to do this I have to do a contains to see if the folder name is in the source attribute. Below is one of the Nodes and then the transform. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Component Id="cmpE4293ADC65367393D7A7630023A43F89" Directory="dirAFEA15D2A28EA2E6080FAD1EE1935E0A" Guid="{691DB98F-E5F4-4979-B2E5-63E14AF8A328}">
      <File Id="filE11EC7DCDC230815BECFE0925B1F3DC4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.publishDir)\WebConfig\appSettings.config" />
 </Component>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

  <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">

    <!-- Just copy the tag itself -->
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:variable name="fvsys" >
        <xsl:value-of select="node()/File/@Source"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Copy all attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <!-- Here comes the distinction: if you find our special component, do some special things -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Note that the string is translated to all lower case, so you don't have to care about being case sensitive or not -->
        <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'WebConfig')">
          <!-- Here we will add the Permanent-attribute to this very special component -->
          <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
       <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Note that the string is translated to all lower case, so you don't have to care about being case sensitive or not -->
        <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'DocumentConversions')">
          <!-- Here we will add the Permanent-attribute to this very special component -->
          <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>


      <!-- Now take the rest of the inner tag -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to add the `Permanent` to the `Component` node, as opposed to the `File` node?

If so, the problem is with how you define the `fvsys` variable:

```
  <xsl:variable name="fvsys" >
    <xsl:value-of select="node()/File/@Source"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

There are two problems here. Firstly, because you are already positioned on a  `Component` node, this will be looking for a `File` node which is a "grand-child" as opposed to a direct child. Secondly, it looks like the `File` node is also part of the `wix` namespace, so will also need to include the prefix.

Try this instead

```
  <xsl:variable name="fvsys" select="wiz:File/@Source" />
```

Note the use of the `select` on the variable itself. In your original version you creating a copy of the value of the attribute, but in the latter declaration it is still referencing the attribute directly.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used what I listed below.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer I just found one that works here is my transform, this worked for my needs. It marks each file inside the folder as permanent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

  <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">

    <!-- Just copy the tag itself -->
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:variable name="fvsys" >
        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='File']/@Source"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Copy all attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />

      <!-- This will mark all files in the WebConfig folder as permanent -->
      <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Note that the string is translated to all lower case, so you don't have to care about being case sensitive or not -->
        <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'WebConfig\')">
          <!-- Here we will add the Permanent-attribute to this very special component -->
          <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
       <xsl:choose>
        <!-- This will mark all files in the DocumentConversions folder as permanent -->
        <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'DocumentConversions\')">
          <!-- Here we will add the Permanent-attribute to this very special component -->
          <xsl:attribute name="Permanent">yes</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>


      <!-- Now take the rest of the inner tag -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```